# node.js forever cannot start script

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js script on my server that I want to run continuously even after I logout of SSH. I decided to use forever for this.

**Problem:** When I try to start the node.js script using `forever start app.js`, I get the following error. Is there more configuration that is required?

```
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
info:   Forever processing file: app.js
{
  "process": {
    "pid": 24257,
    "uid": 0,
    "gid": 0,
    "cwd": "/home/node/nodejs",
    "execPath": "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "version": "v0.6.2",
    "argv": [
      "node",
      "/usr/local/bin/forever",
      "start",
      "app.js"
    ],
    "memoryUsage": {
      "rss": 13729792,
      "heapTotal": 8367232,
      "heapUsed": 5130572
    }
  },
  "os": {
    "loadavg": [
      0.02734375,
      0.0322265625,
      0.0009765625
    ],
    "uptime": 1474229.393550878
  },
  "trace": [
    {
      "column": 21,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js",
      "function": "getOptions",
      "line": 172,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 17,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js",
      "function": "",
      "line": 210,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 19,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js",
      "function": "apply",
      "line": 355,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 9,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js",
      "function": "_every",
      "line": 28,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 16,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js",
      "function": "apply",
      "line": 352,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 9,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js",
      "function": "_every",
      "line": 28,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 5,
      "file": "Object].invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js",
      "function": "[object",
      "line": 350,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 8,
      "file": "Object].dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/cli.js",
      "function": "[object",
      "line": 67,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 21,
      "file": "Object].start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/lib/flatiron/plugins/cli.js",
      "function": "[object",
      "line": 52,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    },
    {
      "column": 9,
      "file": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js",
      "function": null,
      "line": 470,
      "method": null,
      "native": false
    }
  ],
  "stack": [
    "TypeError: Cannot call method 'reset' of undefined",
    "    at getOptions (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:172:21)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:210:17)",
    "    at apply (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:355:19)",
    "    at _every (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:28:9)",
    "    at apply (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:352:16)",
    "    at _every (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:28:9)",
    "    at [object Object].invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:350:5)",
    "    at [object Object].dispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/director/lib/director/cli.js:67:8)",
    "    at [object Object].start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/flatiron/lib/flatiron/plugins/cli.js:52:21)",
    "    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/lib/forever/cli.js:470:9"
  ],
  "level": "error",
  "message": "uncaughtException"
}
```

**Additional Info**

When installing forever using `npm install forever -g`, I get the following warnings, wonder if its relevant to the problem...

```
npm WARN eventemitter2@0.4.1 package.json: 'contributers' should probably be 'contributors'
npm WARN request@2.1.1 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']
```

Comment: I got this error aswell. Might be an issue with node 0.6.3

Comment: Well, I have exactly the same problem using node 4.12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run process at the back end

```
$ nohup node simple-server.js > output.log &
```

The purpose of [Forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever) is to keep a child process (such as your node.js web server) running continuously and automatically restart it when it exits unexpectedly. It's worth mentioning that there are other tools written to accomplish this task in a more generic way for any program or programming language:

Monit: http://mmonit.com/monit/
Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
Daemontools: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html
Launchtool: http://people.debian.org/~enrico/launchtool.html

Comment: Thanks, that is the link I am following for forever installation and usage. Do you mean I try other methods listed there?

Comment: With `nohup ... > output.log &`, is it possible to see all the console.write outputs?

Comment: `vi output.log` You will get out all the stuffs u printed out as well if any error or warning!!!

Comment: with nohup, can I see the stuff printed out as it is being printed out? Like when I run it as `node app.js`

Comment: No you will not all the outputs are now written in `output.log`

Comment: I'm new to linux, so this may sound weird: Can I let the node.js app continue running even after I log out (like nohup), but still show the stuff that gets printed out by console.log as it gets printed out, even aftr I logout and ssh back in again? Yet still able to enable/disable the realtime printing of messages from the node.js script

Comment: Ya you can run it for ever...It is a server so it should be running continuously bro...With `nohup` script runs at back end that why every thing gets printed out to `output.log`

Comment: I think `screen` can do what I just said, letting the script run in the background while I logout, but still show all the printouts from the script in realtime when I want to see it instead of writing them to a log file which I have to check constantly. However, how can I make node.js restart automatically when crashed, and in `screen` can it both display the output in realtime and still log them to a file?

Comment: You will find your answer here http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/internet/nohup.html

Comment: Well, this answer doesn't help to solve the problem with forever. It's just offer another way to move

Comment: Worth mentioning the source of this answer: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/

Answer (score 6):

I've solved the problem, it was bug in last release and they didn't upload to production, so 
install directly from git:

`use npm install git://github.com/nodejitsu/forever.git -g`

for details see the issue:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/179

Comment: After installing forever like that, it seems that `forever list` does not seem to list the processes that have been started by `forever start [app name]` Are you also experiencing this issue?

Comment: It may seem odd, but **forever list** works when you call it twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also check out http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/ as alternative to forever.js. It has many other helpful features.

You can also use unix command '[screen](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html)' or '[byobu](http://byobu.co)' to keep the ssh sessions from dying.